# how to compare two [drupal-commons] db-dumps - in order to find out where the differences are?

Tags: sql, database, drupal, diff, drupal-commons

I have installed a drupal-commons. During the install it shows lots of too-many-files-open-errors. (guess that this is a performance error). After installing the Commons and going to the site, my site has no style.  www.campus-24.com - see the site . it has no face at all - does it!?

Well i also see that there were only 149 instead 155 tables created - well now i hav the question: how can i compare two db-dumps - in order to find out which tables are missin.

Note: this is not a drupal question (and therefore i am here) it is a honest sql question. But i am only a good user of phpmyadmin. so what can ido!`? How can i compare the two databases in order to find out which 6 tables do not exist in the malicious (/broken) db.

Comment: Check that `/sites/default/files` is writable by your web server (you're currently getting a `The file could not be created.` error which I suspect is caused by that) and that you've remembered to upload the `.htaccess` file as it looks like that's missing.

Comment: hi there - many many thanks i try it out. The Htaccess was rearranged by my server admin - do you think that there is a option missin in the htaccess  _ probably this may cause the error _ what do you tink. Well i alsomst get (go) crazy with the errors. - any and all help is greatly appreciated

Comment: It sounds like the server admin may have removed these lines before the rewrite rule to `index.php`: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, but it's very hard to say without seeing the whole file. Try downloading a fresh copy of Drupal and comparing the two files, you should be able to spot the differences quite easily it's not a long file

Comment: hello clive - you point to a very vera valuable point - your ideas are breathtaking. Note i tried several times to install - all failed. My admin put togehter a special htaccess. Clive with the original htaccess - i cannot see the site at all. But i guess that i (and that means the site-admin [my friend] miss (and have forgotten a important option] see the htacess http://pastebin.de/22149 - what is missing here.- love to hear from you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it may not be an SQL question either. Just use some file compare program.  And compare the 2 SQL files. Try Winmerge: winmerge.org